# How to publish an MVC 6 website in IIS with multiple apps in the src folder

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

When I try to publish an asp.net 5 website with multiple web apps in the 'src' folder. It works okay in `klr` but If I run it under IIS, I get this error:

`Failed to resolve the following dependencies for target framework 'Asp.Net,Version=v5.0'`

Here is a very basic simple project attached that you might want to run under IIS.

http://www.filedropper.com/iissampleapp

**Update:** updating my question as requested.

In the attached project, I just right click on "IISSampleApp" and click publish. Visual studio creates files on local file system, which I then try to run under IIS.  After publish, both of the web apps reside under `src` folder as `src\IISSampleApp` and `src\SubApp`.   The `IISSampleApp` is the main app that should run as website, and it just references a class `DateClass` from `SubApp`.

I have created this sample project to get the answer, my actual project have similar structure and I get the same error.

I have uploaded the Precompiled version of the project here: http://www.filedropper.com/precompilediissample

Below is my generated web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="kpm-package-path" value="..\approot\packages" />
    <add key="bootstrapper-version" value="1.0.0-beta3" />
    <add key="runtime-path" value="..\approot\packages" />
    <add key="kre-version" value="1.0.0-beta3" />
    <add key="kre-clr" value="clr" />
    <add key="kre-app-base" value="..\approot\src\IISSampleApp" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

edit the web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="kpm-package-path" value="..\approot\packages" />
    <add key="bootstrapper-version" value="1.0.0-beta3" />
    <add key="runtime-path" value="YOUR-RUNTIME-BASE-PATH\.k\runtimes" />
    <add key="kre-version" value="1.0.0-beta3" />
    <add key="kre-clr" value="clr" />
    <add key="kre-app-base" value="..\approot\src\YOURPROJECT" />
  </appSettings>    
</configuration>
```

and set the security policy for `\approot`and `\wwwroot`

**update:** updating the answer after question's update

That just can't work like this because the `kpm bundle` command packages website as website and not as class library and you have 2 Startup class which is no good. If you want to share code between 2 website create a class library.

Comment: I think i have the same keys in my web.config in the attached project? What should be the security policy for `approot` and `wwwroot` folders? I have added Network Service access but still not working. Everything works if I put everything in  one webapp. But problem comes when two web-apps are there.

Comment: in the project you provide there's `kpm bundle` output. how did you publish too IIS ?

Comment: I am publishing it through Visual studio 2015 CTP 6 on file system.

Comment: can you give me generated web.config files ? do you publish to 2 locations or just 1 ? do you publish to 1 website containing the IISSample project and the SubApp in a sub web-apps ? can you update your question with the maximum detail of your config ?

Comment: Did you sole your issue? I have a similar problem.